# install and set up cygwin on a flash drive?

Tags: cygwin

so I was doing some research on porting bash to windows and found cygwin as a possible answer. Is there any way to install cygwin and set it up properly on a USB drive? (I tried setting the directory in the installation process to the flash drive but it didn't come out good)

Comment: What exactly was the problem?

Comment: It seems someone was fast to give negative vote without explaining that is a question for `SuperUser` not for `StackOverflow`. Please move there and explain your problem. USB drive is fine just be sure to format NTFS

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to solve this problem also. And to answer your question, yes, there is a way to install cygwin and set it up properly on a USB drive.

If you perform and actual internet search about this topic, the solution will appear immediately, within the top five search results. If you go to this [link](https://github.com/ntmoe/CygwinPortable), you will find instructions to do so. When installing the git, vim, and source-highlight options, I just clicked on all the devel options and it worked perfectly fine for me. Glad I could help.